# How to create first post, fifth post full width, rest in three columns and so on

Tags: theme-development, page-template, twitter-bootstrap, blog-page

I am new to wordpress development, I am leaning how to make a theme from scratch. I don't want to use any plugin to achieve this.

How to create first post/ fifth post/ ninth post full width, rest in three columns and so on.

I tried this but first post is not repeating

```
    <?php get_header() ?>



<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <?php $i = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
        <?php if ($i++ == 0) : ?>
        <div class="col-sm-12 blog">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 p-0">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 align-self-center">
                    <div><h3><?php the_title()?></h3></div>
                    <div><?php the_excerpt()?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 blog py-3">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
            <div><h3><?php the_title()?></h3></div>
            <div><?php the_excerpt()?></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endwhile ?>
    </div>
</div>
 <?php get_footer() ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php get_header() ?>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <?php $i = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
        <?php if ($i == 0 || $i % 4 == 0) : ?>
        <div class="col-sm-12 blog">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8 p-0">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 align-self-center">
                    <div><h3><?php the_title()?></h3></div>
                    <div><?php the_excerpt()?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 blog py-3">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail()?>
            <div><h3><?php the_title()?></h3></div>
            <div><?php the_excerpt()?></div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $i++; endwhile ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer() ?>
```

worked, changed `<?php if ($i++ == 0) : ?> to <?php if ($i == 0 || $i % 4 == 0) : ?>`, can be adjusted as per the layout and number of posts.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use PHP Modulo as described [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php $i = 0; while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();  ?>
<?php if ($i == 0 || $i % 4 == 0) : ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <?php the_excerpt() ?>
</div>

<?php else: ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
<div class="col-sm-12">
      <?php the_excerpt() ?>
</div>


<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: can we do this with bootstrap 4 classes? or by php codes in index.php, I have updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Ricky edited my answer!

Comment: I have attached screenshot, I tried your code which gave me error :( @KiwisTasteGood

Comment: @Ricky glad you got it working! Hope I helped a little! :)

Comment: thanks, ya it helped